# java.io.NotSerializableException: sun.nio.fs.WindowsPath - how to fix it?

Tags: java, serialization, nio

I wrote a simple serialization function in order to store a fileTree representation (based on the composite pattern...), but always get following error:

```
        java.io.NotSerializableException: sun.nio.fs.WindowsPath
```

Unfortunately I couldn't figure out so far how to fix that - anyone else encountered that?

Comment: this exception means:you need implement [java.io.Serializable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) interface...

Comment: I know what it means... but WindowsPath isn't serializable.

Answer (score 2):

Serialize it as a String instead of a Path.

Comment: thanks. Does that mean I should change every occurence of Path to Path.toString()? I'll try it.

Comment: No, it means you should change the `Path` member variable to `String`.