# Spring Batch Failed to serialize object of type: class org.springframework.batch.core.StepExecution

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I have a Spring Batch job with is now giving me an error:
Failed to serialize object of type: class org.springframework.batch.core.StepExecution the Job Listener is printing the following exception:

```
org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecutionException: Flow execution ended unexpectedly
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:140) ~[FlowJob.class:3.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:306) ~[AbstractJob.class:3.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:135) [SimpleJobLauncher$1.class:3.0.6.RELEASE]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_51]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_51]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_51]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_51]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_51]
```

The configuration is as follows:

```
  <job id="job2" restartable="false" job-repository="jobRepository" parent="baseJob">
<step id="job2StepBootstrap" parent="parentJobStep">
  <tasklet ref="job2TaskBootstrap"  transaction-manager="jobsTransactionManager" />
</step>
<listeners>
  <listener ref="job2JobListener"/>
</listeners>
```

More

```
<bean id="jobsTransactionManager"
   class="org.springframework.batch.support.transaction.ResourcelessTransactionManager" />


<bean id="jobRepository"
          class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean">
<property name="transactionManager" ref="jobsTransactionManager" />            
<property name="isolationLevelForCreate" value="ISOLATION_SERIALIZABLE" />    
<property name="validateTransactionState" value="false"/>
```

its not so obvious to me what is wrong, i really appreciate your help. I dont want to save the jobs metadata at all.

```
public class BatchDeploymentTaskBootstrap implements Tasklet, Serializable{

 @Override
  public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution stepContribution,         ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Running Batch Job Task(%s)...  ");
    return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
  }
}
```

I have added the job2TaskBootstrap as you can see even the stripped down version doesn't work.

The complete stack trace printed from the job listener afterJob method.

```
org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecutionException: Flow execution ended unexpectedly
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:140) ~[FlowJob.class:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:306) ~[AbstractJob.class:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:135) [SimpleJobLauncher$1.class:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_51]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_51]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_51]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_51]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_51]
Caused by: org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowExecutionException: Ended flow=job2 at state=job2.job2TaskBootstrap with exception
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:178) ~[SimpleFlow.class:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:144) ~[SimpleFlow.class:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:134) ~[FlowJob.class:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    ... 7 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to serialize object of type: class org.springframework.batch.core.StepExecution
    at org.springframework.util.SerializationUtils.serialize(SerializationUtils.java:49) ~[SerializationUtils.class:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.MapStepExecutionDao.copy(MapStepExecutionDao.java:53) ~[MapStepExecutionDao.class:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.MapStepExecutionDao.saveStepExecution(MapStepExecutionDao.java:83) ~[MapStepExecutionDao.class:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository.add(SimpleJobRepository.java:170) ~[SimpleJobRepository.class:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:302) ~[AopUtils.class:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190) ~[ReflectiveMethodInvocation.class:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) ~[ReflectiveMethodInvocation.class:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[TransactionInterceptor$1.class:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281) ~[TransactionAspectSupport.class:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[TransactionInterceptor.class:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[ReflectiveMethodInvocation.class:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208) ~[JdkDynamicAopProxy.class:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy65.add(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:144) ~[SimpleStepHandler.class:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:64) ~[JobFlowExecutor.class:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:67) ~[StepState.class:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:169) ~[SimpleFlow.class:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    ... 9 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: sun.nio.fs.WindowsPath
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1184) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.writeObject(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1413) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:988) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1496) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
    at org.springframework.util.SerializationUtils.serialize(SerializationUtils.java:45) ~[SerializationUtils.class:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    ... 29 common frames omitted
```

Comment: please share the complete stacktrace, the jobListener does not show the complete one

Comment: added the complete stack trace..

Comment: sun.nio.fs.WindowsPath is not serializable. use a string/URI/URL/java.io.File to store path

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26011679/java-io-notserializableexception-sun-nio-fs-windowspath-how-to-fix-it for a similar question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One or more of your classes used in your step is missing an `implements Serializable` in the class declaration.

Anything saved to the `jobRepository` needs to be serializable. This may be used as part of the step execution context data that is saved.

Comment: As you can see from my config posted here, I have already configured correctly the job repository to be in memory. I have no need to save the jobs

Comment: Still not saving anything to the database, and all objects saved in the context implements serializable interface.

Comment: of course you are right one of the objects saved in the context its super class has a variable of type Path which is not serializable

Comment: perfect explanation, in addition to this - if you are putting anything in applicationContext  for later use - that also needs to be serilizable

Answer (score 1):

I was putting a class's object into my chunkContext inside a tasklet using this command :-

```
chunkContext.getStepContext().getStepExecution().getJobExecution()
          .getExecutionContext().put("objectToBeStored", obj);
```

suppose this `obj` belongs to `class A`, then I made `A implements serializable` and this error was gone.